# API-call via plugin to Server Middleware

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, nuxt.js, vue-storefront

I have configured a plugin and a custom Server Middleware extension.

I am able to call functions via my plugin from the server middleware as seen in the snippet below:

**Plugin:**

```
async function getPriceInitiator() {

        const response = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/api/myCustomServerMiddleware/testFunction",
        });
        return response
      }
    }
```

**Server Middleware:**

```
function testFunction() {
    return "predefindedResponseString";
  });
```

I can not seem to call API's in the server middleware like:

```
async function testFunction() {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: 'https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity',
    });
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}
```

Trying to call API's will give me errors like: "certificate has expired" and will *always* return me an empty data object. What seems weird because I can pass strings in the response, then it does work as shown in the first `server middleware` snippet.

EDIT:
The Certificate error is as follows:

```
certificate has expired                                                                       13:40:29

      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is for you to create a "custom-integration" for you special cases, where you can add new layers without any problem. You can check for example the storybook one :)

https://github.com/vuestorefront/storyblok

Comment: I have already worked out a custom intergration :) That's what I have referred to as the "Server middleware" part of my question.